# Javascript conflict between responsive-menu and responsiveslides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a responsive layout using javascript, responsive-menu and javascript, responsiveslides.
When I have only one javacript at a time on the page, they work fine, but together the responsive-menu doesn't work. If I put the javascript for the responsive-menu at the bottom of the page, the menu works fine but the slide show doesn't work. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is my javascript call out:

```
<script src="respond.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu_files/responsive-menu.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="menu_files/jquery.responsive-menu.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#JQResponsiveMenu1").fdResponsiveMenu({windowMinWidth:1000,autoHighlightCurrentPage:false,subMenuOpenOnClick:false,subMenuTransitionEasing:"easeOutSine",subMenuTransitionDuration:300});
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">        </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="responsiveslides.css" />
```

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  // You can also use "$(window).load(function() {"
jQuery(window).load(function() {

  // Slideshow 1
  jQuery("#slider1").responsiveSlides({
    maxwidth: 800,
    speed: 800
  });

  // Slideshow 2
  jQuery("#slider2").responsiveSlides({
    auto: false,
    pager: true,
    speed: 300,
    maxwidth: 540
  });

  // Slideshow 3
  jQuery("#slider3").responsiveSlides({
    manualControls: '#slider3-pager',
    maxwidth: 540
  });

  // Slideshow 4
  jQuery("#slider4").responsiveSlides({
    auto: false,
    pager: false,
    nav: true,
    speed: 500,
    namespace: "callbacks",
    before: function () {
      jQuery('.events').append("<li>before event fired.</li>");
    },
    after: function () {
      jQuery('.events').append("<li>after event fired.</li>");
    }
  });

});
</script>
```

Comment: You seem to be loading jQuery twice, in different versions. That won't do.

Comment: I'd remove v1.8 and see how that does. If it fails, remove 1.10 instead. Some changes in 1.10 might break your plugins.

Comment: I will try your suggestions, thanks

Comment: Thank you,it works great taking out the v1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not advisable to load more than one version of jQuery on a site. I'd remove v1.8 and see how that does. If it fails, remove 1.10 instead. Some changes in 1.10 might break your plugins.